# Можем ли мы для пользователя сохранять найденный им адрес?

Tags: api

Для бесплатного использования у Яндекса есть условие - "Полученные от API данные должны быть отображены на карте с логотипом Яндекса. Вы не можете изменять или сохранять их".
Также для платного использования у Яндекса написано - если вы изменяете или сохраняете данные, полученные через API, стоимость использования увеличивается на 500 тысяч рублей в год.
Что значит сохранять данные полученные от АПИ, можем ли мы для пользователя сохранять найденный им адрес?